# jQuery: Backstretch plugin - show image loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Backstretch Plugin](http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/) to load some full screen images. Everything works fine, but I'd like it to show the image loading (as it would by default) rather than wait with a blank screen until it completely loads. Is this possible? I'm not a JS expert by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Backstretch plugin is written to apply a set of catch-all DOM properties to stretch the image which are all fired on image load:

```
img = $("<img />")....bind("load", function(e) {
  ...
```

You would have to hack the plug-in to change this behaviour.

In any case, images and pages are displayed differently by different browsers during load, so I'm not sure exactly which behaviour you're after.  One alternative is to use a highly compressed image in the background and replace it after the rest of the page has loaded.  Or just optimized the image so the load time is acceptable.

Comment: How could I modify that bind("load" so that it doesn't wait for the image to load, and just lets it load naturally? In most browsers, images load from top to bottom.

Comment: The logic that determines how to scale and position the image is based on the dimensions of the image, which can't be known before the image load event fires.  Unless there's some very unusual requirement you have to meet, the best way to improve performance is probably through image compression.  What file format is the image?